# Method of solving functional equations

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Is it allowed for functional equations to solve them by saying let $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ for some functions $h$ and $g$, and then finding $h$ and $g$ to find $f$? E.g. let $f(x) = x^2 + g(x)$, and then finding $g$ to find $f$.

I'm terrible at functional equations, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: A question is not stupid just because it's at an introductory level. However, I am a bit uncertain what the question actually is.

Comment: if you represent any function like a sum (product) of two other functions then you can put any conditionals for one of them and try to find other funcion.

Comment: In that equation, if you know $f(x)$ then you know $g(x)$ and conversely.  There really isn't anything to solve.

Comment: I think you are being unfair to the OP. Certainly one is allowed to guess at the form of an answer and to then try to fill in the details based on that guess.  There is a name for this: *Ansatz* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz .  In an exam or contest situation working this way is a gamble, because if the guess is fruitless, you have nothing to show for your wasted time or effort.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes. Just be careful that the definitions are sound. For example, the domains must match. If $f$ was supposed to be a function defined on $\mathbb R$, you can't say $f(x) = 1/x + g(x)$, because that doesn't make sense for $x = 0$, so what is $g(0)$?

It is usually better to set this out as introducing a new function. You are the one defining it, and so it is your responsibility to verify that the definition is sensible. So say it like this (with your example):

> Let $g:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be defined by $g(x)= f(x) - x^2$.

[Then proceed to deduce that, say, $g(x) = x$ for all $x \in {\mathbb R}$.]

> ... therefore $f(x) = x^2 + g(x) = x^2+x$ for all $x \in {\mathbb R}$.

The difficult part here would be the omitted deduction that $g(x) = x$. The functional equation might look simpler when expressed in terms of $g$, but that alone rarely solves it. The key is that "finding $g$" should not mean "find/guess one possible $g$", but find all possible $g$ and prove that there are no others.